# How to get an e-mail notification when I get a new answer or comment at my question?

Tags: discussion, email

How can I get an e-mail if a question of mine in Ask Ubuntu gets a new answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. By default you will get notified once per day about new answers to your questions in the email you have used to set up your Ask Ubuntu account.

You can also change when you receive this email by going to your profile → *Settings* → *Edit email settings* (or just [click here](https://askubuntu.com/users/email/settings/current)) and changing the *Inbox* value to either *3hrs*, *Daily*, *Weekly*, or *Off* (if you don't want to receive email notifications about answers or comments to your questions).

> [image: my email settings]